# Cannot "Install by Cloning"

Tags: tor-install

I am at the phase of installation of TAILS 3.0 where I need to clone TAILS onto my second USB.  when I click the install by cloning button the window closes and no menu comes up at all.  I am hoping that someone knows a fix for this.

Comment: Do you get any useful output from running `tails-installer-launcher -v`? (`-v` enables verbose output to the terminal)

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Applications -> Favorites -> Terminal, type `tails-installer-launcher -v` into the terminal and press return.

Comment: "OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/lib/live/mount/medium'"

Comment: How did you create the intermediary USB stick?

Comment: I downloaded and verified the file via Firefox from tails.boum.org. I then used the suggested program to make the intermediary USB.

Comment: It sounds like something has gone wrong with the creation of the intermediary, this has happened when people use other software to create the intermediary, did you use the executable provided in the link from the installation guide? If yes, I'd try creating the intermediary again.

Comment: I retried the whole process and it works perfectly now.  Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting with the intermediary but this time, set an Administrator password. Now when booted fully into tails, launch the Terminal and type 'sudo tails-installer-launcher'. It will ask for your Administrator password that you set on start-up. This will provide the Tails installer the proper elevated privileges to install by cloning.

Answer (score 0):

Just use QubesOS, clone the medium - and it will work out of the box. To make things running smoother - keep in mind that if you will use a router VM not of the disposable type(template-based) - clean the keys on a cloned machine before launching router VM, so Tor will generate new ones on startup and it will work just out of the box with all the rest of your settings